# Ubuntu runs extremely slowly in dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, performance, windows-10, 16.10

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.10 alongside Windows 10 on a 64-bit machine. While the *Try Ubuntu without installing* option ran very smoothly and quickly, the installed Ubuntu runs extremely slowly (much slower than the virtual machine I used previously). The speed of Windows is not influenced from the dual boot. How can this be fixed?

System information:

- 64-bit PC
- Intel i5-4590 3.3GHz
- 4095MB NVIDIA GTX-970 (MSI)
- RAM: 16 GB dual-channel DDR3
- motherboard: ASRock B85
- few hundreds GB of empty disk space
- Windows OS: Windows 10 Home 64-bit Build 14393

I've run "top" in the terminal. This is the result:
[image]

During about 1 minute, the CPU use of Xorg varied in the range 12%-98%, most of the time it was around 25%. When I open programs other than the terminal, the usage rises to ~100%.

Comment: Dual boot or standalone is irrelevant in both cases, for both OSes, meaning the problem has nothing to do with being in dual boot. Your question needs to be edited and updated, at least, with **detailed hardware information**.

Comment: @user1767774 Have you check which processes are showing high? and also check harddisk s.m.a.r.t status with `smartctl` command.

Comment: I've added a photo of the result of "top" command. With regard to smartctl, I am not familiar with this command, could you please specify the flags with which I should run it?

Comment: @user1767774 Have you installed the latest drivers for your GPU? It seems that's why your system is under such load.